# Design a word processor

Tags: java, design-patterns, flyweight-pattern

I came across an interview question asking to design a word processor.

After my research I found Flyweight design pattern as an approach. I came up with below code (ignore syntax). But I am having hard time thinking of what will be my key and what will be my value for word processor.
public class Format
    {
        public readonly string _fontname;
        public readonly string _weight;
        public readonly int _size;

```
    public Format(string fontname, string weight, string size)
    {
        _fontname = fontname;
        _weight = weight;
        _size = size;
    }
}

public class TextFromatInfo
{
    public _readonly Format _oFormat
    public TextFormatInfo ( Format oformat)
    {
        _oFormat = oFormat;
    }
    public Format GetFormat
    {
        get {return this._oFormat}
    }

    public void ApplyFormat(format Format)
    {
        console.writeline ("apply format fontname: " format.forntname +
           "size: " +  format.size + "weight : " format.weight
    }
}

public class TextFormatFactory
{
    public readonly IDictionary<Format, TextFormatInfo> _cache =
       new Dictionary <Format, TextFormatInfo>

    public TextFormatInfo GetTextFormatInfo(Format oFormat)
    {
        if (_cache.ContainsKey(oFormat)) return _cache[oFormat];
        var OTextFormatInfo= new TextFormatInfo(oFormat);
        _cache.add(OTextFormatInfo.GetFormat, OTextFormatInfo);
        return OTextFormatInfo ;
    }
}

public class TestFlyWeight
{
    private static TextFormatInfo[] formtInfo = new TextFormatInfo[100];
    private static TextFormatFactory ff;

    public void ProcessesWord(char c, string fontname, int size, string weight)
    {
    }
}
```

How would the above class look like? How can I complete the program by actually processing word?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think they were maybe not so much interested in patterns as in architecture. But you might have given sufficient material for them to digest.

I would say MDI is a key topic here: multiple document interface. Multiple tabs with several documents.
Having one Document object per file system file (twice opening the same file), and possibly having several DocumentViews (swing: JTextPanes) per Document, bridged by the DocumentListener. In different tabs or in a vertically split single tab, so you may scroll to another spot and still remain at the first spot in split panes. _Specially stress, that this is se

Maybe building swing's EditorKit and StyledDocument.

So to make points of UI knowlegde, creativity, features, existing classes.

*This all said, Patterns are an important asset in interviews too, I have experienced.*